# Drupal 8 Custom form with popup

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to show my custom form in popup when user click a link from front end, I have try many solution that show in web but doesn't work for me.

Here is my code.

```
        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        // Get the modal form using the form builder.
        $modal_form = $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\fwsactions\Forms\FwsActionsForm');
        $modal_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
        // Add an AJAX command to open a modal dialog with the form as the content.
        $modal_form = render($modal_form);
        $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand('My Modal Form', $modal_form, ['width' => '800']));

        return $response;
```

what should i do to open this form with clicking a link only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$content['overlay_link'] = array(
     '#type' => 'link',
     '#title' => $this->t('Add movie'),
     '#url' => Url::fromRoute('node.add', ['node_type' => 'content_type_movie']),
     '#attributes' => [
       'class' => ['use-ajax'],
       'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
       'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
         'width' => 700,
       ]),
     ],
   );
```

Please check [here](http://www.innoraft.com/blog/popups-drupal-8-no-problem) for more details.
Here is one more [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221085/how-to-open-a-popup-form-from-a-view-link) which might help, though both are same but still sharing.

Hope this helps.